# in Java I get an error, that says close parenthesis is expected

Tags: java, syntax-error, parentheses

my Main class look like the following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Account account=new Account();
        account.deposit(amount:10);
        System.out.println(account.getBalance());
    }
}
```

and Account class as below:

```
public class Account {
    private float balance;
    public void deposit(float amount){
        if(amount>0)
        balance+=amount;
    }
}
```

I get an java ) expected error, which refers to the line "account.deposit(amount:10);" in Main class and hints, that amounts can not be resolved, but i dont understand why, could you give me some hint.

Comment: just *account.deposit(10.0);*

Comment: what do you mean by `amount:10` ?

Comment: BTW, don't use float for money : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
account.deposit(amount:10);
```

to

```
account.deposit(10);
```

or

```
account.deposit(10.0f);
```

You can't label parameters that way at the caller's site. Also, don't forget to implement `getBalance()`. And use brackets (`{}`) even when they're optional.